# KeyedAppStates aren't reported to the AMAPI

Tags: feedback, android-management-api, android-enterprise

I have implemented the feedback channel with the KeyedAppStates in my application.
I'm calling `KeyedAppStatesReporter.setStatesImmediate(hashSetOf(state))` where `state` is a keyedAppState created with the builder, but nothing is reported on the AMAPI side.

The profile/policy is set correctly, the ApplicationReports are activated, the application can receive managed configurations correctly when send from the EMM and apply them.

I tried with the Test DPC following the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/work/app-feedback/testing) "Test app feedback". And the Test DPC received the feedbacks send by my application.
[Screenshot of the Test DPC notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVUGC.png)

What could be blocking the reporting of the keyedAppStates to the AMAPI with the real DPC ?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue somehow? If so how? We are facing the same problem.

Comment: @MisterJack49 Is this issue fixed? We are facing the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue on the DPC/AMAPI side.

The issue was resolved with a DPC update not long after, and now it works with the example from the documentation.